# Sharepoint-hosted app deployment failed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a Sharepoint-hosted app with workflow to send email using Sharepoint-2013 as in this  [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt148590.aspx). When I tried to deploy, it failed with the following error message.

**Error message.**

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': Failed
>   to install SharePoint Add-in. Please see the output window for
>   details.

**Detailed message.**

> Active Deployment Configuration: Deploy SharePoint Add-in
>       Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.
>   Skipping the uninstall step because the SharePoint Add-in is not installed on   the server.
>       Install SharePoint Add-in:
>   Uploading the SharePoint Add-in...
>        Installation is in progress (00:00:01)
>    Installation is in progress (00:00:03)
>    Installation is in progress (00:00:05)
>    Installation is in progress (00:00:07)
>    Installation is in progress (00:00:09)
>    Installation is in progress (00:00:12)
>    Add-in failed to install, cleaning up...
>   Successfully uninstalled the SharePoint Add-in. 
>    Add-in installation encountered the following errors:
>    10/13/2016 9:57:30 AM
>        @"Error 1
>           CorrelationId: 4f7a7a1d-83fc-41d8-af27-829d5486d4e5
>           ErrorDetail: There was an error during the operation.
>           ErrorType: Configuration
>           ErrorTypeName: Configuration
>           ExceptionMessage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>           Source: Common
>           SourceName: Common App Deployment

All it says is the problem is regarding `Configuration` and `object reference not set`.Couldn't figure out the reason.

**[Edit]**
But it works if I do it using Sharepoint designer.
I would appreciate any help in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You create some object in your code, that haven`t reference to class in project.
Type

```
using <assemblyName>; //at begine of your custom code code
```

In Visual Stuido incorrect object nderlined by a wavy line
Or addin parent class to incorrect object
Also, you can comment code for deploy testing

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your reply looks like a comment rather than a answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). If you intended to Answer, read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to follow the SO guidelines.